# Ruby - how to group by array of objects?

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by

I am new to ruby and trying to group array of objects. I have below 2 inputs:

```
Inputs:


DEPT = {
    main_dept1: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    main_dept2: ['D', 'E']
}

data = [
{:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100}, 
{:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200}, 
{:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300}, 
{:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
{:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500},
]
```

I want to write an efficient ruby code to group array `data` and get below output from array. In output I want to sum `count` based on `DEPT`

```
output:

{:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}
```

Please suggest best way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original post, a good approach would seem to be using the block form of [Hash#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) to transform your current Hash into a new hash-of-hashes, using the value of each element's :id value as a key. You can then deconstruct each element, and use a single pass through the *data* Array to sum the :count values that match your department arrays. For example:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| h[key] = { main_dept1: 0, main_dept2: 0 } }
data.each do |e|
  id, dept, count = e[:id], e[:dept], e[:count]  
  h[id][:main_dept1] += e[:count] if DEPT[:main_dept1].include? dept
  h[id][:main_dept2] += e[:count] if DEPT[:main_dept2].include? dept
end

h
#=> {123=>{:main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}}

h[123]
#=> {:main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}
```

This won't give you quite the output you're looking for, but it will give you a *single* Hash where each key is an ID. If you want to coerce that back to an array-of-hashes, go right ahead, but a single Hash seems much more useful to me for *using* the tabulated data. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

I have expanded the array `data` to include a second value for the key `:id`.

```
data = [
  {:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100}, 
  {:id=>456, :dept=>"E", :count=>600},
  {:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200}, 
  {:id=>456, :dept=>"B", :count=>900},
  {:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300}, 
  {:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
  {:id=>456, :dept=>"C", :count=>100},
  {:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500},
]
```

---

I suggest that as a first step you convert `DEPT` into a mapping of departments to main departments:

```
dept_to_main_dept = DEPT.each_with_object({}) do |(main_dept,depts),h|
  depts.each { |dept| h[dept] = main_dept }
end
  #=> {"A"=>:main_dept1, "B"=>:main_dept1, "C"=>:main_dept1,
  #    "D"=>:main_dept2, "E"=>:main_dept2}
```

If you don't do that you will have to effectively execute the following method multiple times, each requiring a linear search, which is relatively inefficient.

```
def dept_to_main_dept(dept)
  DEPT.find { |main_dept, arr| arr.include?(dept) }.first
end

dept_to_main_dept('D')  
  #=> :main_dept2
```

---

We can now obtain the desired hash as follows.

```
data.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.
     map do |id,arr|
       arr.group_by { |g| dept_to_main_dept[g[:dept]] }.
           each_with_object(id: id) do |(main_dept,e),f|
             f[main_dept] = e.sum { |d| d[:count] }
           end
     end
  #=> [{:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900},
  #    {:id=>456, :main_dept2=>600, :main_dept1=>1000}]
```

---

The steps are as follows.

```
h = data.group_by { |h| h[:id] }
  #=> {123=>[{:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100},
  #          {:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200},
  #          {:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300},
  #          {:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
  #          {:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500}],
  #    456=>[{:id=>456, :dept=>"E", :count=>600},
  #          {:id=>456, :dept=>"B", :count=>900},
  #          {:id=>456, :dept=>"C", :count=>100}]}
```

The first key-value pair of `h` is passed to `map`'s block and the block variables are assigned values by Ruby's application of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
id, arr = h.first
  #=> [
  #     123,
  #     [
  #       {:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100},
  #       {:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200},
  #       {:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300},
  #       {:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
  #       {:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500}
  #     ]
  #   ]
```

We see that `id #=> 123` and `arr` equals the array of hashes.

The block calculation is as follows.

```
g = arr.group_by { |g| dept_to_main_dept[g[:dept]] }
  #=> {:main_dept1=>[{:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100},
  #                  {:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200},
  #                  {:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300}],
  #    :main_dept2=>[{:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
  #                  {:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500}]}
```

I will now insert two `puts` statements to show how the transformation of `g` is done.

```
g.each_with_object(id: id) do |(main_dept,e),f|
  puts "main_dept = #{main_dept}, e = #{e}, f = #{f}"
  f[main_dept] = e.sum { |d| d[:count] }
  puts "  f after sum = #{f}"
end
  #=> {:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}
```

The following (after some manual formatting) is displayed.

```
main_dept = main_dept1
e = [{:id=>123, :dept=>"A", :count=>100},
     {:id=>123, :dept=>"B", :count=>200},
     {:id=>123, :dept=>"C", :count=>300}]
f = {:id=>123}
f after sum = {:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600}

main_dept = main_dept2
e = [{:id=>123, :dept=>"D", :count=>400},
     {:id=>123, :dept=>"E", :count=>500}]
f = {:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600}
f after sum = {:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}
```

This is then repeated for each other value of `:id`.

Answer (score 0):

Preface: This is not a great data structure to solve the problem. You'd probably be better off storing this information in database, instead of using hashes-of-arrays and arrays-of-hashes.

You also didn't specify how to handle multiple `id`s; the desired output you've stated wouldn't make sense if there are two or more `id`s.

But with that said, here's my initial attempt at a solution:

```
grouped_data = data.group_by { |entry| entry[:id] }

result = grouped_data.map do |id, group|
  { 
    id: id,
    **DEPT.map do |name, depts|
      {
        name => group.select { |entry| depts.include?(entry[:dept]) }.map { |entry| entry[:count] }.sum
      }
    end.inject(&:merge)
  }
end

# This gives the output of:
# result = [{:id=>123, :main_dept1=>600, :main_dept2=>900}]
```